# How to get a twitter news feed

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

How do I get a user's news feed just as they would see it on twitter. I am working on a website where the user logs in to twitter and the page shows them their feed without them going to twitter.

Comment: I guess you're looking for this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: What you looked at the twitter api? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: For a cut-and-paste widget: twitter.com/about/resources/widgets

Comment: I have looked at those solutions and none of them match my problem. I need a solution that shows all the people i follow's activity instead of just mine as that is not what it shows on the twitter homepage.

Answer (score 1):

See this snipet example:

```
<?php 

$fname = "../tmp/twitter.cache.html"; 

// Sistema de cache - tentando recuperar 
    if (file_exists($fname)) { 
if (time() - filemtime($fname) < 240) { 
        echo file_get_contents($fname);     
        exit; 
    } 
}  

ob_start(); 

?> 

<style> 
ul li { 
    list-style:none; 
} 
</style> 

<?php  
    $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=unilogica&count=35';   
    $xml = @simplexml_load_file($url);   

    $twitter = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=unilogica")); 
    $avatar = $twitter->profile_image_url; 

    if (!isset($xml->channel->item)) { 
       echo "<center>Oops, Twitter instavel...</center>"; 

       exit; 
    } 


    foreach(@$xml->channel->item as $node){   
        $node->title = substr($node->title, 10); 

        $offset = strpos($node->title, ' RT @'); 

        if ($offset !== false) { 
            $screen_name  = substr($node->title, $offset+5, strpos($node->title, ':', 2) - $pos - 5); 
            $twitter = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=$screen_name")); 

            $node->title = str_replace(" RT @$screen_name:", "<img width=\"32\" height=\"32\" align=\"left\"  src=\"{$twitter->profile_image_url}\">", $node->title); 

        } else { 
            $node->title = "<img width=\"32\" height=\"32\" align=\"left\" src=\"{$avatar}\"> ".$node->title; 
        } 

        echo '<ul>';   
        printf('<li><div class="twitter-msg-container"><a href="%s" style="color:#069; font-family: arial, verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;" target="_blank">%s</a></div></li>',   
            $node->link,   
            $node->title   
         );   
         echo '</ul>';   
     }  

$buffer = ob_get_clean(); 

@file_put_contents($fname, $buffer); 

echo $buffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help, just change the username and it will give you the twitter feed in json format.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=2&amp;include_rts=true&amp;screen_name=TWITTERUSERNAME"></script>
```

Comment: API v1 is going to be deprecated. It's better you update to `1.1` the URL.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using widgets. Twitter has a very simple widget system where you can embed a Twitter feed on to a website. Check it out [here](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new).

There's also [this](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/), which uses jQuery and styles the Twitter feed quite nicely.

But please do a Google search before turning to StackOverflow. Anyone could have found the links I provided you within two seconds of Googling.

Comment: But this widget does not solve my problem. The widget only shows things i have posted, favorited or retweeted but I want to see all the tweets from people i follow as well as my own activity

Comment: So pretty much load their entire Twitter feed on your site?

Comment: yes I want their entire feed to show up

Comment: I'm not sure if any API exists for what you're looking for. Maybe other SO members will be able to help you out.